# How to get retrieve objects in rails console in a has_many through relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

so i have users ,airlines and review .An airline   has_many :reviews
has_many :users,through: :reviews.A user  has_many :reviews has_many :airlines,through: :reviews and a review belongs to an airlines and user.A user can experience multiple airlines.I dont understand a way to get all the reviews of a user of  travelling by a particular airline.

```
here is my seed data
singapore_airlines=Airline.create(name: 'Singapore Airlines')

cathy=User.create(name:"Cathy",email:"cathy@jetsetgo.com",admin:false)


Review.create(image:"https://worldofwanderlust.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/866D61D2-FFD1-4392-9596-0E4E372D18D9.jpg", date: DateTime.new(2021, 11, 1),destination:"Singapore to Tokyo",seat:"Business class",description:"If you want comforting long flights always take Singapore airlines",likes:0,dislikes:0,airline_id:singapore_airlines.id,user_id: cathy.id)
```

so im aware in the console i can do something like
sing=Airline.find(1)  and then sing.reviews.........but that will give me all the reviews of singapore airline. i want only the review given by cathy.

Comment: are you looking for  something like this? `singapore_airlines.reviews.where(user_id: cathy.id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this directly, you could do:

```
singapore_airlines.reviews.where(user_id: cathy.id)
```

Or:

```
cathy.reviews.where(airline_id: singapore_airlines.id)
```

Or:

```
Review.where(user_id: cathy.id, airline_id: singapore_airlines.id)
```

...Or if this is a common lookup, you could consider making a convenience method for it such as:

```
class Airline < ApplicationRecord

  # ...

  def reviews_for_user(user)
    reviews.where(user_id: user.id)
  end

  # ...

end

# Usage:

singapore_airlines.reviews_for_user(cathy)
```